# Hadoop: How can I give every value a global unique ID number as key in Mapper?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Here is what I want to do. Now I have some text files like this:

```
<page>
<url>xxx.example.com</url>
<title>xxx</title>
<content>abcdef</content>
</page>

<page>
<url>yyy.example.com</url>
<title>yyy</title>
<content>abcdef</content>
</page>

...
```

And I want to read the file split in mapper and convert them to key-value pairs, where each value is the content in one `<page`> tag.

My problem is about the key. I can use urls as keys because they are global unique. However, due to the context of my job, I want to generate a global unique number as a key for each key-value pair. I know this is somehow against the horizontal scalability of Hadoop. But is there any solution to this?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Blocks IDs for each task should be a better choice, since the job can tolerate few collisions in hash. What I should do after I allocate blocks of IDs for each mapper task?

Comment: I would start with putting the task_id and the ID offset you calculated to the configuration so each task can pick up it's starting ID and then start incrementing it. You need to know the number of mappers beforehand and how many records are in a chunk, not impossible to solve, but clunky.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Yes. It is clunky to address. What if I use something like time(milliseconds) to keep keys unique? Can it reduce collisions compared to url Hash?

Comment: It can help, of course. You can emit the generated key in the map stage and sort out collisions while reducing, e.g. by rehashing with the newer timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to process such files by MapReduce I'd take the following strategy:

1. Use general text input format, line by line. This results every different file goes to different mapper job.
2. In mapper build cycle which reads next lines in cycle through `context.nextKeyValue()` instead of being called for each line.
3. Feed lines to some syntax analyzer (maybe you're just enough to read 6 non-empty lines, maybe you will use something like [libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) but finally you will gen number of objects.
4. If you intend to pass objects that you read to reducer you need to wrap them into something that implements `Writable` interaface.
5. To form keys I'd use UUID implementation [`java.util.UUID`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html). Something like:

   UUID key = UUID.randomUUID();

   It's enough if you're not generating billions records per second and your job does not take 100 years. :-)
6. Just note - UUID should be probably encoded in `ImmutableBytesWritable` class, useful for such things.
7. That's all, [`context.write(object,key)`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.Context.html).

OK, your reducer (if any) and output format is another story. You will definitely need output format to store your objects if you don't convert them to something like `Text` during the mapping.

Comment: UUID should be a good solution. But what is its advantage compared to URLHash?

Comment: UUID is really unique if you are using good quality random generator. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates

Comment: BTW even if you use good enough hashing for URL and some ms timestamp as you process URLs at maximum speed you anyway have pretty high duplication probability.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question directly. But I am taking the advantage of the input file format.

You might use the [NLineInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/NLineInputFormat.html) and set N = 6 as each record encompasses 6 lines:

```
<page>
<url>xxx.example.com</url>
<title>xxx</title>
<content>abcdef</content>
</page>
.
```

With each record, the mapper would get the offset position in the file. This offset would be unique for each record.

PS: It would work only if the schema is fixed. I am doubtful if it would work properly for multiple input text files.

Comment: That is a good trial. But as you considered, my input schema is not fixed. The content may consist of several lines...